# I can't add first user in mongodb server

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

[image]

Earlier I created first user witch hasn't "userAdminAnyDatabase" role, I delete that user (so now in my database doesn't exist any user) and I got this. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart your mongod instance with parameter `--transitionToAuth`

Then you can re-create the user. Restart mongod again.

If it does not work, then try option `--noauth`.

Option `--transitionToAuth` disables only the authentication for clients, but [Internal/Membership Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/) remains active. Internal/Membership Authentication is pointless when you run a stand-alone MongodDB, it is relevant only for  replica sets and sharded clusters.

If you run a stand-alone MongoDB then use option `--noauth` (and remove option `--auth`, of course) which disables authentication entirely.

Comment: "BadValue: --transitionToAuth must be used with keyFile or x509 authentication", this is what i got